# Select section of list based on value of a enumeration

Tags: c#, linq

I have a c# app. I have custom list of type result, shown below. The list is called 'myResultList'.

```
enumResult { noResult = 0, win = 1, lose = 2 }

class Result
{
  public enumResult OutCome {get; set;}
  public double Frequency {get;set;}
  public string GroupName {get; set;}
  public double TotalValue {get; set;}
}
```

myResultList contains numerous elements. I wish to select all the elements where the Outcome equals lose into a new list. I believe LINQ is probably best for this task, correct me if I am wrong. How do I go about querying a list based on a enumeration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var lostResults = myResultList.Where(r => r.OutCome == enumResult.lose).ToList();
```

NOTE: Consider to have Pascal Case names for types and public members. And don't include prefixes in type names. E.g.

```
public enum Outcome
{
    NoResult,
    Win,
    Lose
}
```

---

If you will need to filter results by other types of outcomes, then consider to use lookup:

```
var results = myResultList.ToLookup(r => r.OutCome);
```

Then getting results by their type will be easy:

```
var wonResults = results[enumResult.won];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var newList = myResultList.Where(r => r.OutCome == enumResult.lose).ToList();
```